# Counting number of columns that have value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table where similar to"

```
no   type    category    a     b    c    d
1    plan      avg       5     4    3    
2    plan      avg             3         3
3    plan      est       2     1         2
4    plan      est       6     4   
5    forecast  avg             4         3
```

I want to create a new column where it will count number of columns that have value in the 4 last columns.

```
no   type    category  counts  
1    plan      avg       3
2    plan      avg       2
3    plan      est       3
4    plan      est       2
5    forecast  avg       2
```

How can I do that in python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `count()` method directly for the dataframe. The `count()` method returns the number of non-NaN values in each column.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
df['New'] = df.iloc[:,-4:].ne('').sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest and most efficient way to do the job also you can specify if only numeric values have to be counted

```
  df['counts']=df.iloc[:, -4:].count(numeric_only=True,axis=1)
```

You can count the number of values in columns as well instead of rows by using  axis=0  checkout  [df.count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for more info.